# Perform a database query on a form and display results in a field of the same form in yii2

Tags: forms, yii2

I have a form where I request data from an address with the fields cp_consulta, colonia, street, etc.this data will be stored in a table called address, this table has a one to one connection with a table called colonia that has stored data.
When the user enters a value in the "consulta" field, I want to trigger an AJAX function that performs a database query to find all matches in the "colonia" table where the "codigo_postal" field is equal to the value entered in the "cp_consulta" field.
Then, the results of this query should be used to populate the "add_fkcolonia" field in the form of dropdown options. The value of the "add_fkcolonia" field will be updated with the option selected by the user.
I have made the form and a controller attempt which should work.

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\models\Colonia;
use yii\bootstrap5\ActiveForm;

/**
 * @var yii\web\View $this 
 * @var app\models\Address $address
 * @var app\models\Colonia $colonia
 */

$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Inicio', 'url' => ['/site/index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = 'Dirección';

$this->title = 'Dirección';

$colonia = Colonia::findOne($address->add_fkcolonia);

?>


<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<div class="address-create">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($address, 'cp_consulta')->textInput(['id' => 'cp_consulta']) ?>
    <?= $form->field($address, 'add_fkcolonia')->dropDownList($colonias, ['prompt' => 'Seleccione una colonia', 'id' => 'add_fkcolonia', 'options' => ['prompt' => 'Seleccione una colonia']]) ?>`

    <?= $form->field($address, 'add_street')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($address, 'add_exterior')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($address, 'add_note')->textarea(['rows' => 4]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>


</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cp_consulta').on('change', function() {
            var cp_consulta = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/supplier/address/get-colonias',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    cp_consulta: cp_consulta
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        $('#add_fkcolonia').empty();
                        $.each(response.colonias, function(key, value) {
                            $('#add_fkcolonia').append($('<option>', {
                                value: key,
                                text: value
                            }));
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

controller

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\supplier\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Address;
use app\models\Colonia;
use app\controllers\BaseController;

class AddressController extends BaseController
{
    public function actionRegister($id)
    {
        $supplier = $this->findModel($id, null, User::class);
        $address = new Address();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $cp_consulta = Yii::$app->request->post('Address.cp_consulta');

            if ($cp_consulta) {
                $colonias = Colonia::find()
                    ->where(['codigo_postal' => $cp_consulta])
                    ->all();

                $coloniaOptions = [];
                foreach ($colonias as $colonia) {
                    $coloniaOptions[$colonia->id] = $colonia->nombre;
                }

                return $this->asJson(['success' => true, 'colonias' => $coloniaOptions]);
            }

            $address->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            if ($address->validate()) {
                $address->save();
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('_form', compact('address'));
    }

    public function actionGetColonias()
    {
        $cp_consulta = Yii::$app->request->post('cp_consulta');

        $colonias = Colonia::find()
            ->where(['codigo_postal' => $cp_consulta])
            ->all();

        $coloniaOptions = [];
        foreach ($colonias as $colonia) {
            $coloniaOptions[$colonia->id] = $colonia->nombre;
        }

        return $this->asJson(['success' => true, 'colonias' => $coloniaOptions]);
    }}
```

I have done two actions to do what I want but the dropdown list of the form does not show the matches with cp_consulta that are stored in the colonia table.